# PDO, $_GET, and SELECTing from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

So I'm working on a PHP Pastebin-esque project on my freetime to learn PHP and server management, and I've run into a LOT of issues, and I haven't been able to solve them. I decided to restart from sratch on my own with the information I've gathered so far, and threw this code together.

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';
        $getid = $_GET["id"];
        $sql = 'SELECT paste FROM pasteinfo WHERE id=:id';
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param(':id', trim($_GET["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT));
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['paste'];
        }

?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve with this code is a system where a user can type the **id** of whatever paste they're interested in viewing in the url and have it display the pasteinfo row, which is the row that holds the paste itself. The format they should have is viewpaste.php?id=(user input).

How can I fix this code? I would also greatly appreciate if you explain whatever code you might end up putting in the comments so I can learn from it. Thanks!

Comment: PDO or mysqli?? http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php != http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php Also usage is inverted example: `$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);`. and `execute` is a function so `$stmt->execute();`. or alternatively you could just bind in the execute `$stmt->execute(array(':id' => trim($_GET["id"])));` (assuming this is PDO as tagged and some of the code is written)

Comment: Additional note, you don't select `id` so that index will never be populated. `echo $row['paste'];`. Per update `bind_param` is still incorrect, look at the PDO link.

Comment: @chris85 Made all those changes and updated the code in the OP, but still not getting anything. Does the echo perhaps have to be formatted differently or something?

Comment: You never used the `bindParam` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

connection.php

```
try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;charset=utf8mb4', 'database_username', 'database_password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch (PDOException $ex){
echo $ex->getMessage();return false;
}

function retrieve($query,$input) {
 global $db;
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute($input);
 $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);   
 return $stmt;
}
```

To retrieve data, call the retrieve() function

Retrieval page, say display.php

```
require 'connection.php';
$getid = $_GET["id"];
$result=retrieve("SELECT paste FROM pasteinfo WHERE id=?",array($getid));
$row=$result->fetch();
//To get paste column of that id
$paste=$row->paste;
echo $paste;
```

Comment: forgot to tag you in that last post

Comment: No they are different file

Comment: yeah, I tested it and it worked exactly how I needed it to. Could you give me a general overview as to how the code works though?

Comment: I would have love to but this is not a good platform for explanation but giving solution. Notwithstanding i love fetching my data as an object it is quite clean and straightforward.

Comment: It definitely feels that way. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, messed up a little lol. Added a 'Title' column and already updated everything for it, but I simply cannot get your code to fetch both paste and title. Mind giving me a hand?

Comment: $title=$row->title; echo $title;

Comment: Check you query it says "SELECT paste FROM pasteinfo WHERE id=?" change it to "SELECT * FROM pasteinfo WHERE id=?" or "SELECT paste,title FROM pasteinfo WHERE id=?"